# Changing ion-input color

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-input` component in my application, I'm trying to set a color for dark mode, but I can't figure out how I can change the color of the whole component.
I tried setting the `ion-input` color, but it does not color the whole field, this is how it looks:

[image]

This is my html:

```
<div class="goal-title-input ion-padding">
    <div class="icon-title">
        <ion-icon name="trophy-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label class="app-small-title">What's your goal?</ion-label>
    </div>
    <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-input placeholder="This is placeholder text" (ionChange)="onChangedTitle($event)"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="trophy-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

This is my css file:

```
.goal-title-input {
    ion-item {
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 13px 30px 0px rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.09);
        padding: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;

        ion-icon {
            font-size: 21px;
            margin-right: 16px;
            color: var(--ion-color-medium);
        }

        ion-input {
            padding-left: 10px !important;
            border-left: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
            background-color: var(--ion-color-danger);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess it is because of the padding, but I can't figure out how to color the rest of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an element in the Shadow DOM `<div class="item-native">` within `<ion-item>`, if you give this container the same red/pink background it will cover the entire input. You can use [CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts) to style CSS properties for an element inside of a shadow tree. If you target the nested `<div class="item-native" part="native">` container using [`::part`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) inside of `<ion-item>`. The following style could be applied:

```css
ion-item::part(native) {
  background-color: var(--ion-color-danger);
}
```

A bit of whitespace will still exist around the `<ion-input>` due to `padding: 8px` on `<ion-item>`. If you remove that padding, the entire container will have a background of `var(--ion-color-danger)`. Have a look at the [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-styling-shadow-dom).

[image: StackBlitz demo image]